# Display a mat-icon inside mat-select and display both as selected using mat-select-trigger

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working in Angular 7 and one of the requirements that I have is to create a mat-select with mat-icons. The issue I'm up against is I can either get the icons to show or I can get the option label to show but not both. What I need to do is be able to chain the value, but I got an error when I tried.

The mat-select is set up as so-

```
    <button mat-raised-button type="button" name="button" color="primary" class="roundedButton">
    <mat-select [(value)]="selected2">
      <mat-select-trigger><mat-icon>{{selected2}}</mat-icon>{{selected2}}</mat-select-trigger>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        <mat-icon>{{food.icon}}</mat-icon>{{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

I have placed the selected icon and label in the mat-select-trigger and the value to food.value.

The interface for the select is

```
export interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
  icon: any;
}
```

and the select options are set up as

```
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', icon: 'add', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', icon: 'lock', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', icon: 'search', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];
    public selected2 = 'steak-0';
```

If I change the value to be food.icon I can get the select options icon to appear as the selection. If I change value to food.viewValue I get the label of the option to appear.

How can I get both when a user makes a selection?

I have set up a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hajkw6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to show the setup and issue in action.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of setting the value to the `icon` or the `viewValue`, set it to the entire object. This way the selected value will contain the data in the entire object. Then you can simply use the properties in the selected object to get what you want.

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button type="button" name="button" color="primary" class="roundedButton">
        <mat-select [(value)]="selected2" [compareWith]="compareFn">
            <mat-select-trigger><mat-icon class="selection-icon">{{selected2.icon}}</mat-icon><span>{{selected2.viewValue}}</span></mat-select-trigger>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food">
                <mat-icon>{{food.icon}}</mat-icon>{{food.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

Now both `icon` and `viewValue` will show in the select trigger. All you need to is fix the css of the icon since it doesn't appear inline with the `viewValue`.

```css
.selection-icon {
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

Here is a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-raised-button-select).

**Note**: In order to set the value of this selected object, you can either pass an object from the original array itself (for eg. `public selected2 = foods[0]`) or you can use `compareWith` so that the `select` will be able to track the values since our option `value` is an object. This is similar to the `trackBy` in `ngFor`. Basically, either pass a reference from the original array so the `select` can track it or use `compareWith` to tell the `select` to track the objects in the arrays based on some unique value in each object.

Comment: This is great, thank you for the help and the great explanation. Super helpful. I knew it had to be something simple that I was over looking. I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: The example you've added is missing a theme, which causes it to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below:

```
<mat-select #select>
  <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="select.value"><mat-icon>{{select.value.icon}}</mat-icon>{{select.value.viewValue}}</mat-select-trigger>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food">
    <mat-icon>{{food.icon}}</mat-icon>{{food.viewValue}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!